# Is this a good scanf alternative?

Tags: c, io, scanf

```
void fill_boxes(box *boxes, int length)
{
    char *n;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("Enter box %d id: ", i+1);
        //scanf("%d",&boxes[i].id);
        fgets(n,25,stdin);
        boxes[i].id = strtol(n,NULL,10);

        printf("Enter box %d name: ", i+1);
        //scanf(" %49[^\n]",boxes[i].name);
        fgets(boxes[i].name,50,stdin);

    }
}
```

I tried this method to replace scanf and it looks like the input() function in python where it takes the input as a string and then you convert it to whatever type you want, which is what I'm doing with fgets() then strtol().
I'm asking if this is a good alternative to scanf or are there better solutions available ?

Comment: but also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/1216776

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` is good, when passed valid arguments.

`fgets(n,25,stdin)` is bad in this code as the value of pointer `n` is indeterminate.

- Instead of using pointer `char *n;`, use an ample sized array like `char buffer[100];`.  I recommend 2x the expected max size.
- Use `sizeof` to determine array size, not a magic number.
- Check `fgets()` return value.
- Avoid using both `fgets()` and `scanf()` in the same program.  I recommend using `fgets()` only until your understand why `scanf()` is problematic.

```
void fill_boxes(box *boxes, int length) {
    // char *n;
    char buffer[100];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("Enter box %d id: ", i+1);
        // fgets(n,25,stdin);
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer ,stdin) == NULL) {
          printf("No valid input\n");
          break;
        }
        boxes[i].id = strtol(n,NULL,10);

        printf("Enter box %d name: ", i+1);
        // fgets(boxes[i].name,50,stdin);
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer ,stdin) == NULL) {
          printf("No valid input\n");
          break;
        }

        snprintf(boxes[i].name, sizeof boxes[i].name, "%[^\n]", buffer);
        // or
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0; // Lop off potential \n
        snprintf(boxes[i].name, sizeof boxes[i].name, "%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

Additional code concerns:

- What should happen if the line of input is excessively long?
- What should happen with errant input like `"123 zxfc\n"` for `boxes[i].id`?
- `fgets(boxes[i].name,50,stdin);` is a problem as rarely is the trailing `'\n'` desired in `boxes[i].name`.  Zeroing the `'\n'` after the read, limits reduces by 1, what could  be stored in `boxes[i].name`.